# How to change specific part of a text file without deleting the rest?

Tags: python, list, replace

I am trying to code a python program that stocks the username, password and score you've entered. That part I believe to be working. My issue is when I reopen the program, I want to have the new score from that username and password added onto the old score, but what I've tried either deletes the rest of the text file or modifies the password as well as the score (say it wrote  <123> <2> and you wrote 2 as the score next time, it would become  <143> <4>). I only want it to change the score but not the password or username, how do I go about this?

Here's some part of the code I having difficulties with:
In the following, here's what is written in the text file -- nate 123 2

```
for line in open("test.txt","r").readlines():
        score_info = line.split()
 
        if user == score_info[0] and password == score_info[1]:
            oldscore = int(score_info[2])
            newscore = int(count) + oldscore
            score_info[2] = str(newscore)
            file = open("test.txt","r+")
            file.write(score_info[0])
            file.write(" ")
            file.write(score_info[1])
            file.write(" ")
            file.write(score_info[2])
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
```

Comment: Don't give the code but instead give a minimal working example

Comment: @IanQuah just added the code

Comment: Changing "a" or "w" to "r+" fixes the solution if I use only one user, but once it has more than one user and you don't write the one first found in the text file, it overwrites that name and changes it to the one found on the second line, which obviously I do not want because now I just have twice the same information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there could be multiple solutions. Perhaps three text files?

Since it is work with strings in a singular text file, a nice tool to have in your back pocket is Regular Expressions. If you want to take the time to learn about them, they would be well suited to this task and many others you'd have in the future.

If you have time to paste the code; it would be helpful.

Comment: This answer is really more suited for a comment (I've done this before a bunch too, DWBI)